# button background alpha duplication

Tags: android, button, background

I have Button and set background resource to it:

```
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.color00);
```

color00:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/img00" />
  <item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/img00" />
</selector>
```

then I set alpha to this button

```
button1.getBackground().setAlpha(50);
```

and then I have problem. If I set this background resource to button2:

```
button2.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.color00);
```

So button1's alpha set to button2's alpha with this resource. How to fix it?

Comment: button2.getBackground().setAlpha(50);

Comment: I want to have button2 with 100% alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mutate:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/drawable-mutations.html

Drawables use the same state to all their references. User Mutate() for different states.